# How are injected these classes into my Spring controller class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, annotations, spring-annotations

I am pretty new in Spring and I have some doubts about how is injected some classes into a controller class.

Into my project I have this **HomeController** class:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
    @Autowired
    private MessageSource  messageSource;
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    .....................................................
    .....................................................
    .....................................................
}
```

My doubt is related to the 2 objects **MessageSource  messageSource** and **Environment env** classes.

As you can see these classes are injected by the **@Autowired** annotation.

The problem is that I have not bean definition into my XML configuration for these classes. So why are correctly injected? Where are the definition of these bean?

Tnx

Comment: Please post your xml configuration and the beans definition too (i'm prety sure they are defining themselves with annotations)

Comment: Can you show the import statments?

Comment: Beans can be defined not only in xml, but using annotations, `@Service` for example. If container finds one that matches given class or interface, it injects it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic discovery of beans is based on the following rules:

> 1) Use context:annotation-config tag in spring-config.xml to let
>   Spring use Annotations
>   2) Use context:component-scan tag in
>   spring-config.xml and tell Spring the package in which to look for
>   auto-discovering beans
>   3) Use @Component annotation to mark a class
>   as a Spring auto-discoverable bean

If `@Component annotation` is used, then the bean declarations need not be declared in spring-config.xml

Answer (score 1):

Spring mappings can be done with `XML` or with [annotations](http://simplespringtutorial.com/annotations.html).

In your case, if no XML defined, your `MessageSource` and `Environment` classes should be mapped by [Spring annotations](http://simplespringtutorial.com/annotations.html) like [`@Component`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html) `@Service` or `@Resource`:

**[`@Component`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/stereotype/Component.html)**

> Indicates that an a**nnotated class is** a "component". Such classes are considered as **candidates for auto-detection** when using annotation-based configuration and classpath scanning.

**`@Autowired`**

> **@Autowired annotation will try to find a bean of type Foo in the spring context** and will then inject the same.

**`@Resource`**

> Similar to this is @Resource annotation that will try to find the bean with the name "foo". To summarize, @Autowired wires by type and @Resource wires by name.

Answer (score 0):

Both the [Environment](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) and the [MessageSource](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/MessageSource.html) are closely tied to the inner workings of Spring Framework.

The environment is part of the application context and will be available for autowiring.

The ApplicationContext interface extends the MessageSource interface and will be available for autowiring as a message source, even if you have not defined your own message source bean. (If you define your own message source, the application context will [delegate to that](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-messagesource))